# Sort directory list alphabetically

Tags: sort

I need to sort the directories alphabetically descending and piping to sort is not working.

```
alias ld='ls -altp | grep ^d|sort -n'
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! It is generally a [really bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) to parse the output of `ls`.  You should probably look into either using `find` or simple shell globbing to get your list of files to process.  Extensive further reading on the subject can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls).

Comment: What's wrong with the default lexicographical ordering of the output of `ls`?

Comment: OP appears to be trying to find only _directories_.

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Don't parse the output of `ls`.  It's a bad idea and doing so will make you feel bad.  Instead, `find` the directories, and let `ls` sort them for you *without then trying to chew on its output*:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | xargs -0 ls -ld
```

Cheerfully, `ls` already lexographically sorts its output by default.

More simply, there is `tree`:

```
$ tree -d -L 1
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ls -ld */
```

This will give you the directories in the current directory in `ls` long format, in lexicographical order. If a file is a symbolic link to a directory, this will be listed as a directory too.

If you have `ls` aliased to something, then use `command ls` or `\ls` instead of just `ls` above.

The trailing slash after `*` will ensure that the `*` expands to only directories (possibly by resolving symbolic links), and it will be included in the output too.  The `-d` option will make sure that the directories themselves are listed, not their contents.

As [Jeff points out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/441850/116858), naming your alias `ld` is a bad idea since it collides with the name of an existing utility.

Answer (score 0):

You're telling `sort` to sort the long listing of `ls` *numerically*. That's after telling `ls` to sort the listing by modification time (`t`)!

My best suggestion for a short fix would be:

```
ls -d */ | sort # optionally `-f` to sort upper- and lower-case together.
```

I'd suggest a shell such as zsh that can select directories *and* sort them by itself:

```
zsh -c "ls -ld */(on)"
```

Where the `/` specifies that you only want directories, and the `(on)` qualifier says to sort the list based on their name.

I would also recommend against overloading the [`ld` program name](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld).

```
alias lls='zsh -c "ls -ld */(on)"'
```